# Finding the index value of the smallest number in a list?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of numbers `[ 20, 15, 27, 30 ]`

How would I return the index number of the smallest value in this list. (`15`) Obviously, min(lst) will return the smallest number itself, but how do I instead return it's index "`1`" ?

Answer (score 41):

Since you already know how to find the minimum value, you simply feed that value to the `index()` function to get the index of this value in the list. I.e,

```
n = [20, 15, 27, 30]
n.index(min(n))
```

yields

```
1
```

This will return the index of the minimum value in the list. Note that if there are several minima it will return the *first*.

[min()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min): With a single argument iterable, return the smallest item of a non-empty iterable (such as a string, tuple or list). With more than one argument, return the smallest of the arguments.

[list.index(x)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):
Return the index in the list of the *first* item whose value is x. It is
an error if there is no such item.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> L = [20, 15, 27, 30]
>>> min(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__)
1
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option depending on complexity of data:

```
import heapq
s = [20, 15, 27, 30]
heapq.nsmallest(1, ((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(s)))
```

Comment: This is (likely) faster in general because the best known worst case complexity bound for building a heap is O(n), whereas comparison sorts have an O(nlog(n)) worst case bound.  However, it would still be good to profile the two implementations to ensure that the Python implementations of these data structures is consistent with the best case bounds.

Comment: I like this because it would work on an iterator.

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to @Jon Clements's answer.  His uses `heapq` which means it can be used to find more than one smallest value.  Instead of using `itemgetter()` he simply reverses the order of the values in the tuples so they naturally sort in the correct order.

If all you need is the single smallest value, this is an easy way:

```
from operator import itemgetter
lst = [20, 15, 27, 30]
i, value = min(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1))
```

`enumerate()` is the usual way in Python to pair up values from a list and their indices; it returns an iterator that yields up tuples like `(i, value)` where `value` is a value from the original sequence and `i` is the index of that value within the sequence.  `min()` can take an iterator; the `key=` argument is set to a function that ignores the paired index value and just finds the minimum second value (index 1) within each tuple.

`min()` returns the tuple it finds with the min value and then we use tuple unpacking to assign the values to `i` and `value`.

The example shown is a list, but this would work with any sequence including an iterator:

```
from random import randint
def rseq(n=20):
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield randint(0, 101)

i, value = min(enumerate(rseq()), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Note that `itemgetter(n)` is a factory that makes callable objects.  With `itemgetter(1)` you get a callable that returns the second item (index 1) in a sequence (in this case, a tuple).  You could also write a function or a `lambda` function to do the same thing:

```
def get1(x):
    return x[1]
i, value = min(enumerate(lst), key=get1)

i, value = min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: And of course, using `itemgetter` (at least in CPython) takes the execution of the code out of Python and into the C level.

Comment: @Jon Clements, I wonder if it would be faster to just build the tuples in reversed order, as your answer did.

Comment: I doubt the performance would/should be a bottle-neck significantly different - although I have been corrected before. Taking a bit of code from 1 month to execute to 3 days - I'm happy with. Bothering about a bit that goes from 2mins54s to 2mins30 - I can't be bothered with - I'm not operating hospital systems, and am IO bound anyway, so :)